# Namespace merging with enums in modern typescript

Tags: typescript, enums, es6-modules

The general opinion that I've gathered from reading around online is that it is [recommended to use modules instead of namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#using-modules) in modern ES6 code. However, I would like to add some static functions to some enums that I have, and the cleanest way of doing this seems to be with namespace merging, as described [in the TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces-with-classes-functions-and-enums).

Is there a more modern way of adding static functions to enums?

Comment: I guess namespaces are still the only way to put static members on some other structures. Modules definitely won't fill this use case.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I just don't like it I guess. Makes me feel like I should be doing something else.